# Account confirmation and password recovery doesn't want to work using SendGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sendgrid

There are many tutorials on how to enable account confirmation and password recovery in asp.net, however none of them seem to work for me. I tried using SMTP but that didn't work. I ended up following [this](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/features-api/account-confirmation-and-password-recovery-with-aspnet-identity) tutorial suggested by asp.net. I also didn't find any of the answers on Stackoverflow useful. 
 
I have the following class in `IdentifyConfig.cs` where "xxxxx" is substituted by my credentials.

```
    public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
    {
        public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
        {
            return configSendGridasync(message);
        }

        private Task configSendGridasync(IdentityMessage message)
        {
            var myMessage = new SendGridMessage();
            myMessage.AddTo(message.Destination);
            myMessage.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(
                                "xxxxxx", "xxxxxx");
            myMessage.Subject = message.Subject;
            myMessage.Text = message.Body;
            myMessage.Html = message.Body;

            var credentials = new NetworkCredential(
                       ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["xxxxxx"],
                       ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["xxxxxx"]
                       );

            // Create a Web transport for sending email.
            var transportWeb = new Web(credentials);

            // Send the email.
            if (transportWeb != null)
            {
                return transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage);
            }
            else
            {
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }
        }
    }
```

I have uncommented the code in `AccountController.cs` to enable email confirmation and password recovery.
`Register` action:

```
        public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, UserFirstName = model.UserFirstName, UserSurname = model.UserSurname };
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

                    // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                    // Send an email with this link
                    string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                    var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                    await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                AddErrors(result);
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

`ForgotPassword` action

```
        public async Task<ActionResult> ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
                if (user == null || !(await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id)))
                {
                    // Don't reveal that the user does not exist or is not confirmed
                    return View("ForgotPasswordConfirmation");
                }

                // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                // Send an email with this link
                string code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
                var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);      
                await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Reset Password", "Please reset your password by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");
                return RedirectToAction("ForgotPasswordConfirmation", "Account");
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

I have also enabled SSL for my project.

---

When I register a new user it loads for a while then I get the following error:
`Exceptions.InvalidApiRequestException: Bad Request Check 'Errors' for a list of errors returned by the API.`
The error occurs in `await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");` in my `Register` action found in `AccountController.cs`.
Stack trace:

```
[InvalidApiRequestException: Bad Request Check `Errors` for a list of errors returned by the API.]
   SendGrid.ErrorChecker.CheckForErrors(HttpResponseMessage response, Stream stream) +566
   SendGrid.<CheckForErrorsAsync>d__0.MoveNext() +429
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() +21
   SendGrid.<DeliverAsync>d__0.MoveNext() +641
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() +21
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.CultureAwaiter.GetResult() +63
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.<SendEmailAsync>d__129.MoveNext() +963
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() +21
   Splend.Controllers.<Register>d__f.MoveNext() in c:\Users\Bongumusa\Business\Projects\Splend\Splend\Controllers\AccountController.cs:164
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() +21
   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.ThrowIfFaulted(Task task) +61
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +114
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +66
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +136
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +117
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +323
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +136
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +72
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +185
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +38
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +129
```

Quite frankly, I don't understand this stack trace as I am new to asp.net. And as a result, I don't know where to start debugging to trace the problem.

---

**What seems to be the issue?**

Comment: I'm not familiar with this particular problem. But just judging by the error message it sounds like `InvalidApiRequestException` might have an `Errors` property that you should check for relevant details. Try wrapping the offending code in a try/catch block, catch `InvalidApiRequestException` and see if it has an `Errors` property. If so, log the error or inspect it in the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

At this point, I concluded that the C# API for SendGrid is really limited and is no help to provide more detailed error messages, or allow to handle errors gracefully. You can get a better sense of what's going on by using fiddler and looking at the message returned by the server. Once you're in a production environment, all bets are off. Good luck!